Do I need to set Open Graph URL on each page of my NextJS app router application?
I'm using NextJS app router to build my web app. I'm working on SEO and social previews right now, for which metadata is important.
In my layout.tsx file, I have code like:
export const metadata: Metadata = {
  metadataBase: new URL('https://www.oasis-of-ideas.com'),
  title: pageTitle,
  description: pageDescription,
  keywords: [],
  authors: [{ name: 'Author' }],

  openGraph: {
    type: 'website',
    url: '/',
    title: pageTitle,
    description: pageDescription,
    images: [
      {
        url: '/logo-high-res.png',
        width: 500,
        height: 500,
        alt: 'Open Graph Image',
      },
    ],
  }
}

and then in each individual page, I change tags as needed:
export const metadata: Metadata = {
  title: 'Changed title',
  openGraph: {
    title: 'Changed title'
  }
}

Now from what I understand, the opengraph url tag is supposed to refer to the canonical url, which in my simple case is just the url of the current page. I want the crawlers to look at the opengraph image of that page itself. Ideally then, the og:url should be optional, but i read online that it is required. It seems kinda unintuitive why one would want to require it.
Some questions:

Is including openGraph url explicitly required?
If so, how do i do it for each nextjs page? any simple way to do it?
Can i locally preview my website's social previews somehow? if not, after i deploy it, what tools can i use to review it?

I looked online, but couldn't find a lot of clear docs on this. Thanks!

After setting metadataBase, you can set og:url as a relative path.
export const metadata: Metadata = {
  metadataBase: new URL('https://example.com'),
  openGraph: {
    url: './',
  },
}

